# Why are my checkboxes unchecking when changing Page? WPF C# .NET

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

So basically.. I added 2 new pages in a frame and when I press a button it changes frame..

But if I check a checkbox on the first page it wont be checked if I go to another page and then go back to the first one..

here is a more visual look http://recordit.co/Py3zptKLck

Source code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CheckboxesAndPages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            main.Content = new SecondPage();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            main.Content = new thirdPage();
        }
    }
}
```

There is no source code for the 2 pages.

Comment: Looks like you need to also have some variable to hold the content of SecondPage() and thirdPage() when they aren't set to main.Content. They are getting replaced each time you assign new SecondPage or thirdPage on main.Content.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving it a new SecondPage every time

```
SecondPage secondPage = new SecondPage();
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    main.Content = secondPage;
}
```